# Eigenvalues/eigenvectors for this Hermitian matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am having some trouble to compute the eigenvectors of the following Hermitian matrix:
\begin{eqnarray}A=
\left(\begin{matrix}
a+J && V && V  && 0\\
V && a + 2(h-J) && 0 && J\\
V && 0 && a-2(h+J) &&J\\
0 &&J && J && 0
\end{matrix}\right)
\end{eqnarray}
By making the condition $A\vec
x = \lambda\vec{x}$ for the eigenvectors, I obtain that for $\vec{x}=(x_{i})_{i=1...4}$ that by choosing $x_{3}=\frac{1}{a-J-2h-\lambda}$:
\begin{eqnarray}
x_{1}=\frac{2V(a-J-\lambda)}{(\lambda-a-J)((a-\lambda-J)^{2}-4h^{2})} \hspace{10pt} x_{4}=\frac{2J(a-J-\lambda)}{\lambda((a-\lambda-J)^{2}-4h^{2})} \hspace{10pt} x_{2}=\frac{1}{a-J+2h-\lambda}
\end{eqnarray}
knowing that since $A$ is Hermitian, $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$. So it seems for the eigenvectors, one can freely choose $x_{3}$, which I fixed above. The problem is now on how to actually compute the eigenvectors from here, as the equation for $\lambda$ looks pretty horrendous. Any suggestions on how to proceed, for instance, to compute a first value of $\lambda$ that satisfies the eigenvalue equation without needing to solve the characteristic polynomial roots? This would then reduce the $\lambda$ equation to order $3$ instead of $4$. Choosing $\lambda=a-J$ is kind of close, but does not satisfy the eigenvalue equation as one can check.

Comment: Is there any reason for you expect the eigenvectors to be less "horrendous" than the eigenvalues?

Comment: My hope is that, by exploiting the structure of the matrix, one can come up with a way to solve for at least one of the eigenvectors, by inspection or any other method than just solving directly the full equation for $\lambda$. The others would follow by solving the resulting $3x3$ matrix subspace of the remaining eigenvalues.

Comment: But the coefficients of the eigenvector will necessarily depend on the eigenvalues (as you actually wrote), and the four of them are horrendous. Just to give you an idea, I made [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=eigenvalues++%7B%7B11%2B5%2C7%2C7%2C0%7D%2C%7B7%2C11%2B2h-10%2C0%2C5%7D%2C%7B7%2C0%2C11-2h%2B10%2C5%7D%2C%7B0%2C5%2C5%2C0%7D%7D) calculate the eigenvalues/eigenvectors for concrete values of $a,V,J$. The expressions on $h$ are still terrible, both for the eigenvalues and the eigenvectors.

Comment: I actually had tried Wolfram for this before, and I saw the form of the eigenvalues, but from my past experience sometimes Mathematica does not simply give the simplified expression... anyway I assume this is just the way it is and there is no work around for this, only writing the full horrible form. Thank you for your interest.